# Use pdf-table-extractor directly with axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This script is run in server using NodeJS,
I want to use pdf-table-extractor with remote file input directly from axios, is that can be done ?

here is what i have tried

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const pdf_table_extractor = require("pdf-table-extractor")
const getPDF = await axios.get(`domain/a.pdf`,{responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
pdf_table_extractor(new Uint8Array(getPDF.data))
```

the error say `The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received Uint8Array(118456)`

Answer (score 0):

[pdf-table-extractor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-table-extractor/v/1.0.2) is expecting a filepath and you are passing a typed array. It can't work this way.

There are many options, one of them is to save the data from `getPDF.data` to disk using [writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options), and then provide the path of the saved file to `pdf_table_extractor`.